# How to search and display a specific string from rawhtml using MongoDB

Tags: regex, string, mongodb

I need to display only a the domain and DNS server's name from a rawhtml file.

I tried the `$regex`:

```
db.builtwith1.find({"rawhtml":{"$regex":".*'content= "Web technologies'.*"},"rawhtml":{"$regex":".*'is using on their website'.*"}}})
```

but I am not getting the desired output.

EG rawhtml:

```
^!DOCTYPE html>^html>^head>^meta charset="utf-8" />^link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//trends.builtwith.com" />^link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//trendspro.builtwith.com" />^link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api.builtwith.com" />^title>
JUSTPATERSON.CO.NZ Technology                                                                                                                                                               Profile^/title>^meta name="description" content="Web technologies JUSTPATERSON.CO.NZ is using on their website." />^meta name="viewport" ......
```

Of this text I need to just extract `JUSTPATERSON.CO.NZ`

Can anyone suggest a generalized result using mongo shell?

Comment: Is that an actual sample of your source text or are the `^` characters representing `<` which are standard in HTML?

Comment: Its an actual sample of my source text

Comment: of the complete html code it ll be great if i get a way to extract just the domain...using mongodb